# Inverter uma string a partir de um caractere

Tags: string

Queria um método para pegar um campo do lado duma string e passar pro outro lado depois do caractere '=', exemplo:

```
  ColorPickerButton1.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorKeyword
  ColorPickerButton2.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorPreprocessor
  ColorPickerButton3.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorString
  ColorPickerButton4.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorNumber
  ColorPickerButton5.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorText
  ColorPickerButton6.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorBackground
  ColorPickerButton7.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorNumericCount
  ColorPickerButton8.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorIndent
  ColorPickerButton9.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorFoldingIndicator
  ColorPickerButton10.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorCaret
```

Queria que invertesse o que está sendo atribuído para o que está sendo recebido. Exemplo com o primeiro item:

```
  ColorPickerButton1.SelectedColor = My.Settings.getColorKeyword 'antigo
  My.Settings.getColorKeyword = ColorPickerButton1.SelectedColor 'novo
```

Algum site, método, alguma coisa que faça isso? (tenho umas 50 linhas para inverter, não queria fazer isso manualmente).

Comment: Não sei se existe alguma ferramenta que faz exatamente isso, mas resolvi brincar e fiz uma: https://alanmol.shinyapps.io/RevEqual

Comment: Qual linguagem? Ou isso é algo pra ser feito uma vez só e pronto? Se seu editor de texto suporta expressões regulares no "localizar/substituir", basta você localizar `([^=]+)[=]([^\n]+)\n` e substituir por `$2=$1\n`. [Exemplo](http://www.regexr.com/3bb0r)

Comment: Qual é essa linguagem de programação? Me parece ser VB, mas há outras linguagens que poderia ser, então o melhor seria se você esclarecesse isso.

Comment: VB.NET, eu achei um jeito fácil aqui, no caso selecionar no modo coluna e mandar pra frente de tudo.

Comment: @Molx essa ferramenta era o que precisava, valeu!